# Should methods have PHPDocs for uncaught exceptions?

Tags: php, phpdoc, api-design

Let's say in a class, I have these very contrived methods:

```
/**
 * @param bool $flag
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException _bubbled up_ if $flag is not bool
 */
public function fu($flag){
    $this->bar($flag);
}

/**
 * @param bool $flag
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if $flag is not bool
 */
private function bar($flag) {
    if (!is_bool($flag)){
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('bool required');
    }
}
```

Since only `fu()` is public, developers viewing my API may not see that `bar()` could throw an exception.  I felt it was a good idea to add the extra `@throws` tag to `fu()` so developers would know they may want to catch an exception when they call it.

Is this a good idea or is it bad?  Why?

Comment: Can you do it consistently for **all** exceptions that may occur in your function? Where you draw the line? How valuable are docs that contain only **some** of the exceptions?

Comment: Coming from a Java perspective where all (*checked*) exceptions have to be either handled or listed in the throws clause I think it would be a good idea to always list the exceptions that can be thrown by a method / function whether it originates in that method or not. If it is really feasible in PHP, especially if you incorporate third party code, is another matter...

Comment: @AlexBlex: `@throws` states which exceptions the method could possibly throw explicitly (or by design).  Other exceptions from the method are either from a bug in it or were thrown by other code it calls.  If the other code stated it throws exceptions which my method doesn't catch, then my method should state them in `@throws`.  @hsan mentioned that, too. Why don't most methods state all the exceptions? Is it laziness or there's a good reason? I want to know whether it's bad to list the exceptions not caught by my method, but are known to be thrown by code it calls.

Comment: That's it. `If the other code stated it throws exceptions` is a BIG `if`, and even **if** you could find such libraries, and use only them, it will probably result with quite long list of uncaught exceptions on the top level classes. Most of them will make no sense to you. I believe the common practice is to catch all exceptions anyway. In the rare case when you need a handler for specific exception,  you probably already know what exception you are catching.